# Combobox.requery does not work in a subform on another form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I asked related question before but it didn't solve the problem. So, I am posting it again with more details.

I have a form `frmMain` that contains a subform `frmSub`. `frmSub` contains a combobox `subCombo`. In the Not_in_List event of `subCombo`, I have following code:

```
If msgbox ("Do you want to add this data in list?", vbYesNo) = VbYes then
   DoCmd.OpenForm "frmList", acNormal,,, acFormAdd, acDialog, NewData &";"
Response = acDataErrContinue
DoCmd.CancelEvent
Me.ActiveControl.Undo

End if
```

This opens the `frmList` where I successfully add this newdata and in the save button there, I have the code to update the row source for `subCombo`:

```
DoCmd.Save
Me.Refresh

'make new data available in subCombo on frmMain
Forms!frmMain.frmSub.form.subCombo.Requery
```

But this last line of code is not working. Thus, subCombo remains unaffected.
I am not sure what is causing this problem. Would appreciate if you can help in that.

Comment: You should edit your previous question rather than posting a near identical one.

Comment: I am sorry, I'm new here and not well aware of rules. Will take care next time. For now, I am posting the solution to my problem here and will delete the other one.

Answer (score 0):

[Refer to Form and Subform properties and controls](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm)

You need

```
Forms!frmMain!frmSub.Form!subCombo.Requery
```

Note the additional `.Form`

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake in my post, just fixed it. In my code, I have .form mentioned. Also updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem solved finally!

Turns out that I did not need to requery the `subCombo` from `frmList` since it was opened in a `acDailog` mode and has paused the previous code on `Not_in_List` event of `subCombo`. Instead I put `me.subCombo.Requery` just before `End If` line within `Not_in_List` event and it works like a charm. Final code looks like:

```
`If msgbox ("Do you want to add this data in list?", vbYesNo) = VbYes then`
`DoCmd.OpenForm "frmList", acNormal,,, acFormAdd, acDialog, NewData &";"`
`Response = acDataErrContinue`
`DoCmd.CancelEvent`
`Me.ActiveControl.Undo`

`End if`
```